# How to await for rows ingested to WAL table to become visible in QuestDB?

Tags: database, questdb

I'm running a single-time QuestDB ingestion for a large data volume. I'm using InfluxDB Line Protocol, and the table uses Write-Ahead Log (WAL). Since inserts are asynchronous, I want to ensure that all ingested rows are visible for read-only queries once I'm done with the ingestion.

Are there any approaches other than running a `SELECT count()` query and checking the number of visible rows?

Answer (score 2):

Running `SELECT count(*) FROM my_table` is certainly a viable approach. Another approach would be to run the following query over the [`wal_tables`](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/function/meta/#wal_tables) table function:

```sql
SELECT 1
FROM wal_tables()
WHERE name = 'my_table' and writerTxn = sequencerTxn;
```

Here, `writerTxn` is the last committed transaction available for read-only queries and `sequencerTxn` is the last transaction committed to WAL. So, if these numbers match for a table, the above query will return a row which means that all rows became visible for queries.